# how to prioritize operations in ( ) for a python calculator where I am given the input as a string?

Tags: python

I am completing a kata in code wars.

I am given a string like `"2 / 2 + 3 * 4 - 6"` or `"2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * 1 ) ) )"`

I can't figure out how to handle ( ) in the code.

Currently I have:

```
class Calculator(object):
    def evaluate(self, string):
        # if () in s
        # find most inner ()
        s = string.split()
        while len(s) > 1:
            if ('/' in s or
                '*' in s):
                for i in range(len(s)):
                    if s[i] == '/':
                        s[i] = int(s[i-1]) / int(s[i+1])
                        s.pop(i-1)
                        s.pop(i)
                        break
                    elif s[i] == '*':
                        s[i] = int(s[i-1]) * int(s[i+1])
                        s.pop(i-1)
                        s.pop(i)
                        break
            else:
                for i in range(len(s)):
                    if s[i] == '-':
                        s[i] = int(s[i-1]) - int(s[i+1])
                        s.pop(i-1)
                        s.pop(i)
                        break
                    elif s[i] == '+':
                        s[i] = int(s[i-1]) + int(s[i+1])
                        s.pop(i-1)
                        s.pop(i)
                        break
        return s[0]
```

which functions great except for strings with ( )

How could I handle them so that it follows proper math rules?

Any suggestion is largely appreciated.
[1]: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5235c913397cbf2508000048/train/python

Comment: Basically you're asking how to write a parser for mathematical expressions - there are lots of resources about this.

Comment: Funny that I "solved" it by `exec ("result = " + string)` `return int(result)` and it said "No cheating! You are not allowed to use "exec" 

Comment: I dont know that this works your question but there are 2 special built in function in python called `eval` and `exec` you can give them a try. `eval('expression string')` will evaluate that string as an expression and return a value. Example usage `eval('2 + 5')` returns `7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for inner parenthesis, then evaluate their content using your function (this is known as *recursion*), and repeat so until you have no parentheses left.

Inner parentheses are parentheses with no other parentheses between them.